# anaconda-navigator not opening on CentOS 7.3

Tags: anaconda

I'm new to Anaconda. I had installed Anaconda24.4.0Linuxx86_64.sh on a  Centos 7.3 server and after installed in the terminal (I use PuTTY as an emulator to connect to the server) I had enter anaconda-navigator. I got the following error message:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the 
Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "".
Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, xcb.
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to overcome this issue? Below my conda info and conda list.

```
conda Info:
platform : linux-64
conda version : 4.3.21
conda is private : False
conda-env version : 4.3.21
conda-build version : not installed
python version : 2.7.13.final.0
requests version : 2.14.2
root environment : /home/AD/soarelu/Download/ENTER (writable)
default environment : /home/AD/soarelu/Download/ENTER
envs directories : /home/AD/soarelu/Download/ENTER/envs
/home/AD/soarelu/.conda/envs
package cache : /home/AD/soarelu/Download/ENTER/pkgs
/home/AD/soarelu/.conda/pkgs
channel URLs:https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64 https//repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
https//repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
https//repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch 
https//repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64 https//repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
config file : None
netrc file : None
offline mode : False
user-agent : conda/4.3.21 requests/2.14.2 CPython/2.7.13 Linux/3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 CentOS Linux/7.3.1611 glibc/2.17
UID:GID : 1946947662:1946800513
```

conda list

```
packages in environment at /home/AD/soarelu/Download/ENTER:

_license 1.1 py27_1
alabaster 0.7.10 py27_0
anaconda 4.4.0  np112py27_0
anaconda-client 1.6.3 py27_0
anaconda-navigator 1.6.2 py27_0
anaconda-project 0.6.0  py27_0
asn1crypto 0.22.0 py27_0
astroid 1.4.9 py27_0
astropy 1.3.2 np112py27_0
babel 2.4.0 py27_0
backports 1.0 py27_0
backports_abc 0.5 py27_0
beautifulsoup4  4.6.0 py27_0
bitarray 0.8.1  py27_0
blaze 0.10.1 py27_0
bleach  1.5.0 py27_0
bokeh 0.12.5 py27_1
boto 2.46.1 py27_0
bottleneck 1.2.1 np112py27_0
cairo 1.14.8 0
cdecimal 2.3 py27_2
cffi 1.10.0 py27_0
chardet 3.0.3 py27_0
click 6.7 py27_0
cloudpickle 0.2.2 py27_0
clyent  1.2.2 py27_0
colorama 0.3.9  py27_0
conda 4.3.21 py27_0
conda-env 2.6.0 0
configparser 3.5.0 py27_0
contextlib2 0.5.5 py27_0
cryptography 1.8.1 py27_0
curl 7.52.1 0
cycler  0.10.0 py27_0
cython  0.25.2 py27_0
cytoolz 0.8.2 py27_0
dask 0.14.3 py27_1
datashape 0.5.4 py27_0
dbus 1.10.10 0
decorator 4.0.11 py27_0
distributed 1.16.3 py27_0
docutils 0.13.1 py27_0
entrypoints 0.2.2 py27_1
enum34  1.1.6 py27_0
et_xmlfile 1.0.1 py27_0
expat 2.1.0 0
fastcache 1.0.2 py27_1
flask 0.12.2 py27_0
flask-cors 3.0.2 py27_0
fontconfig 2.12.1 3
freetype 2.5.5  2
funcsigs 1.0.2  py27_0
functools32 3.2.3.2 py27_0
futures 3.1.1 py27_0
get_terminal_size 1.0.0 py27_0
gevent  1.2.1 py27_0
glib 2.50.2 1
greenlet 0.4.12 py27_0
grin 1.2.1 py27_3
gst-plugins-base 1.8.0  0
gstreamer 1.8.0 0
h5py 2.7.0 np112py27_0
harfbuzz 0.9.39 2
hdf5 1.8.17 1
heapdict 1.0.0  py27_1
html5lib 0.999  py27_0
icu 54.1 0
idna 2.5 py27_0
imagesize 0.7.1 py27_0
ipaddress 1.0.18 py27_0
ipykernel 4.6.1 py27_0
ipython 5.3.0 py27_0
ipython_genutils 0.2.0  py27_0
ipywidgets 6.0.0 py27_0
isort 4.2.5 py27_0
itsdangerous 0.24 py27_0
jbig 2.1 0
jdcal 1.3 py27_0
jedi 0.10.2 py27_2
jinja2  2.9.6 py27_0
jpeg 9b 0
jsonschema 2.6.0 py27_0
jupyter 1.0.0 py27_3
jupyter_client  5.0.1 py27_0
jupyter_console 5.1.0 py27_0
jupyter_core 4.3.0 py27_0
lazy-object-proxy 1.2.2 py27_0
libffi  3.2.1 1
libgcc  4.8.5 2
libgfortran 3.0.0 1
libiconv 1.14 0
libpng  1.6.27 0
libsodium 1.0.10 0
libtiff 4.0.6 3
libtool 2.4.2 0
libxcb  1.12 1
libxml2 2.9.4 0
libxslt 1.1.29  0
llvmlite 0.18.0 py27_0
locket  0.2.0 py27_1
lxml 3.7.3 py27_0
markupsafe 0.23 py27_2
matplotlib 2.0.2 np112py27_0
mistune 0.7.4 py27_0
mkl 2017.0.1 0
mkl-service 1.1.2 py27_3
mpmath  0.19 py27_1
msgpack-python  0.4.8 py27_0
multipledispatch 0.4.9  py27_0
navigator-updater 0.1.0 py27_0
nbconvert 5.1.1 py27_0
nbformat 4.3.0  py27_0
networkx 1.11 py27_0
nltk 3.2.3 py27_0
nose 1.3.7 py27_1
notebook 5.0.0  py27_0
numba 0.33.0 np112py27_0
numexpr 2.6.2 np112py27_0
numpy 1.12.1 py27_0
numpydoc 0.6.0  py27_0
odo 0.5.0 py27_1
olefile 0.44 py27_0
openpyxl 2.4.7  py27_0
openssl 1.0.2l  0
packaging 16.8  py27_0
pandas  0.20.1 np112py27_0
pandocfilters 1.4.1 py27_0
pango 1.40.3 1
partd 0.3.8 py27_0
path.py 10.3.1  py27_0
pathlib2 2.2.1  py27_0
patsy 0.4.1 py27_0
pcre 8.39 1
pep8 1.7.0 py27_0
pexpect 4.2.1 py27_0
pickleshare 0.7.4 py27_0
pillow  4.1.1 py27_0
pip 9.0.1 py27_1
pixman  0.34.0 0
ply 3.10 py27_0
prompt_toolkit  1.0.14 py27_0
psutil  5.2.2 py27_0
ptyprocess 0.5.1 py27_0
py 1.4.33 py27_0
pycairo 1.10.0  py27_0
pycosat 0.6.2 py27_0
pycparser 2.17  py27_0
pycrypto 2.6.1  py27_6
pycurl  7.43.0 py27_2
pyflakes 1.5.0  py27_0
pygments 2.2.0  py27_0
pylint  1.6.4 py27_1
pyodbc  4.0.16 py27_0
pyopenssl 17.0.0 py27_0
pyparsing 2.1.4 py27_0
pyqt 5.6.0 py27_2
pytables 3.3.0  np112py27_0
pytest  3.0.7 py27_0
python  2.7.13 0
python-dateutil 2.6.0 py27_0
pytz 2017.2 py27_0
pywavelets 0.5.2 np112py27_0
pyyaml  3.12 py27_0
pyzmq 16.0.2 py27_0
qt 5.6.2 4
qtawesome 0.4.4 py27_0
qtconsole 4.3.0 py27_0
qtpy 1.2.1 py27_0
readline 6.2 2
requests 2.14.2 py27_0
rope 0.9.4 py27_1
ruamel_yaml 0.11.14 py27_1
scandir 1.5 py27_0
scikit-image 0.13.0 np112py27_0
scikit-learn 0.18.1 np112py27_1
scipy 0.19.0 np112py27_0
seaborn 0.7.1 py27_0
setuptools 27.2.0 py27_0
simplegeneric 0.8.1 py27_1
singledispatch  3.4.0.3 py27_0
sip 4.18 py27_0
six 1.10.0 py27_0
snowballstemmer 1.2.1 py27_0
sortedcollections 0.5.3 py27_0
sortedcontainers 1.5.7  py27_0
sphinx  1.5.6 py27_0
spyder  3.1.4 py27_0
sqlalchemy 1.1.9 py27_0
sqlite  3.13.0 0
ssl_match_hostname 3.4.0.2 py27_1
statsmodels 0.8.0 np112py27_0
subprocess32 3.2.7 py27_0
sympy 1.0 py27_0
tblib 1.3.2 py27_0
terminado 0.6 py27_0
testpath 0.3 py27_0
tk 8.5.18 0
toolz 0.8.2 py27_0
tornado 4.5.1 py27_0
traitlets 4.3.2 py27_0
unicodecsv 0.14.1 py27_0
unixodbc 2.3.4  0
wcwidth 0.1.7 py27_0
werkzeug 0.12.2 py27_0
wheel 0.29.0 py27_0
widgetsnbextension 2.0.0 py27_0
wrapt 1.10.10 py27_0
xlrd 1.0.0 py27_0
xlsxwriter 0.9.6 py27_0
xlwt 1.2.0 py27_0
xz 5.2.2 1
yaml 0.1.6 0
zeromq  4.1.5 0
zict 0.1.2 py27_0
zlib 1.2.8 3
```

Comment: Did you forward X server connections? Most likely, if you're using a terminal emulator, there is no X server for Anaconda Navigator to open windows with. You should just use the command line.

Comment: Hi Darthbith. Thanks for your response and yes I'm using a terminal emulator. Since I'm new to Anaconda if I'm in the server computer itself (not an emulator) the Navigator screen would pop-up, right? Thanks once more for your attention and support.

Comment: If you are sitting at the server, and you have started an X desktop (e.g., Gnome, XFCE, KDE, or some other display server), then you will be able to see the Navigator. However, if all you have is a text display, you will not be able to see the Navigator.